# Jasmine wait for private function that makes an asynchronous call to resolve promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, async-await, jasmine

I have a function `A`, that is a private function inside of a controller. Function `A` is only used **once** inside of my controller:

```
$scope.$on('callA', function () {
    A();
});
```

Inside `A()`, there is a service call that performs an operation:

```
this.aPromise = myService.AsyncTask(var1, var2);
this.aPromise.promise.then(function (response) {
   ...
   $scope.$applyAsync(function() {
      ...
   });
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
it('should perform task A', function () {
   var promise;
   promise = $q.$resolve();
   spyOn(myService, 'AsyncTask').and.returnValue(promise);

   $rootScope.$broadcast('callA'); // call the function
});
```

However I get the following error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**. I traced it back to the following line: `this.aPromise.promise.then(function (response) {`

> I am trying to test the `...` lines of code. How can I make sure Jasmine waits for the promise to resolve before running my `expect()`?

Comment: `$q.$resolve();` doesn't throw an error?

Comment: @CastroRoy It does not throw an error no, but perhaps it is causing the typerror I am seeing.

Comment: You probably need to invoke `$rootScope.$apply();` in order to propagate promise resolution to `.then` functions, or take a look at my answer using `$q.defer()` that will give you the control of when to `resolve` the promise.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `$q.defer()` instead of `$q.$resolve()`

```
it('should perform task A', function (done) { // use the done argument
   var mockResponse = {msg: "Success"};
   var defer = $q.defer();

   spyOn(myService, 'AsyncTask').and.returnValue(defer);

   $rootScope.$broadcast('callA'); // call the function

   $rootScope.$apply(function(){
       defer.resolve(mockResponse); // manually resolve the promise
   });

   defer.promise.then(function(response){
       expect(response.msg).toEqual(mockResponse.msg);

       done(); // Don't forget to invoke done. It tell Jasmine we've finished
   });

   // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
   $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

First, pass a `done` argument to your test, it is used for asynchronous tests. By using `$q.defer()` you have control of when to `resolve` the `Promise`. Place your `expect` inside `.then` if you need to test the result of your promise. I've added an example using the `mockResponse` variable, but it will only work if in your code `this.aPromise.promise.then(function (response) {...` at the end of your function, you return your `response`.

Also, don't forget to invoke `done`, it tells `Jasmine` we've finished with it.

And most important, invoke `$rootScope.$apply();` at the end in order to propagate promise resolution to `.then` functions.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is more promising, but I am still getting an error: `TypeError: vm.aPromise.cancel is not a function`. Inside of my $scope.$on('$destroy, function () { ... } I am calling: `vm.aPromise.cancel({ canceled: true });`

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `cancel` method in the `$q` API. You will need to implement your own `cancel` mechanism. Probably using `$q.race` is the best option.

Comment: Also with this proposed solution, I am not able to enter the `$scope.$applyAsync(function() { ... }` lines of code as mentioned above.

Comment: Do you mean the callback function passed to `$scope.$applyAsync`? You will need to update your question and show a little bit more of your code.

Comment: I believe in my original question, I included `...` to indicate sections of my code where I would like my unit tests to enter and test. But yes, I am referring to the callback function passed to `$scope.applyAsync`.

Comment: See my edited answer, you need to invoke `$rootScope.$apply()` twice, with the first invoke you `resolve` the promise in the callback of the `apply`, with the second you will trigger the `$scope.applyAsync` inside your function `A`. Hope it helps.